# Performance Issue in latest ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, performance

I have recently installed the latest ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on my laptop. but while using I am facing performance issue. slow response when launching software. even a single task takes time to perform.

sometimes hanging.

My laptop Specifications:

2.10 GHz Intel Processor.
x64 based Processor.
2 GB RAM.
4 GB HDD space as SWAP.
Installed on 20 GB HDD Partition.

Do you have any solutions/Fix?

Comment: install htop and take a look at the processes. use a terminal for this. with f6 you can sort by cpu or memory usage. in the upper corner you can see how busy your cpu threaads are and how much memory is used in general. also take a look at the load average (5m 10m 15m). 

is your system out of memory? is it using swap? are the cpus busy? also which processes use the most resources.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu with GNOME may be too heavy for your computer to handle, I recommend trying a community maintained distro such as Xubuntu 18.04, It's Ubuntu, but with an interface that is lighter on your computer, and you still have access to all the games and software you can on regular Ubuntu, without the speed drawbacks!

The download page for Xubuntu is here: https://xubuntu.org/download/

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 worked fine for me with GNOME